# Changing body data attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute, skrollr

I'm using skrollr and want to make the entire body of my page change colors/gradients.  I can do this with my current code which is:

```
<body data-start="background-image:linear-gradient(rgb(4,21,41), rgb(31,16,66));" data-end="background-image:linear-gradient(rgb(31,16,66), rgb(66,16,52));">
```

However, upon loading of an iFrame (which is triggered by a form submit), I want to change the gradient for the body.  I thought changing the `data-start` values might do the trick so I tried:

```
<iframe onload="if(submitted)
{$('body').attr('data-start','background-image:linear-gradient(rgb(4,21,41), rgb(31,16,66))'}">
```

But that hasn't worked. I've tried other jQuery functions that do work when the iFrame loads (e.g. `$('#idName').hide()`).  But the .attr() function doesn't seem to work and I'm thinking something with skrollr is interfering. I've also tried the .data() function but that doesn't seem to change data values either.

Does anyone know how I might change the body gradient after a certain trigger (e.g. submitting a form)?

Comment: It's less an issue with the value not being updated, and more the fact that updating it doesn't do anything. There'll be a script that does something with that data-start attribute on the body tag when the page loads, but it won't continue to check to see if you update the value; find out what that script is, what function needs to be called, and call it yourself after updating the value.

Comment: Why not change the gradient directly on the body style without changing the data attributes?

Comment: I haven't worked with skrollr, but you likely would need to re-initialize skrollr, if it supports that.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#refreshelements) it seems that `refresh` should do:

> Useful when: ... Data-attributes are manipulated dynamically.

```
var skroll = skrollr.init(/*...*/);

// when needed
skroll.refresh();
```